# Why does chmod not work on bash emulation on windows?

Tags: permissions, git, ssh-keys

I have just installed [Git 2.30.1 for windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) and generated ssh keys with `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "me@email.com"`.
My private key has the permission 644 and I can't change it with chmod. When I run  `chmod 600 id_ed25519` there is no error or effect in the permissions for this file.

I am aware that Windows and it's filesystem does not support unix-like permissions but I need to set them in order to be accepted by the other side (a bitbucket instance). Anyone else have this problem?

#### Why do I believe that the permissions are the problem?

I can connect via ssh from another machine using the same key with correct permissions. According to [sshd's manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config#:%7E:text=HostKey) your private key will not be accepted if it is group/world-accessible.

#### Update

Cygwin and Git-Bash show different results when viewing the permissions of the key file:

```
# Cygwin
-rwx------+ 1 myUserName someGroup 464 Feb 11 16:43 id_ed25519
```

```
# Git-Bash
-rw-r--r-- 1 myUserName someGroupNo 464 Feb 11 16:43 id_ed25519
```

Comment: of course you can't run `chmod` on Windows. You can only change the permission on a \*nix environment like wsl or cygwin. `I need to set them in order to be accepted by the other side (a bitbucket instance)` bitbucket doesn't know how the permissions are set and doesn't care about that

Comment: @phuclv: Well, the MSYS environment that comes with Git is _supposed to be_ a "*nix environment" just like Cygwin (only more lightweight), as it is necessary in order to support the shell-based components of Git like 'git-rebase', so it comes with bash, chmod, and whatnot... but apparently they've made it a bit _too_ minimal and didn't include the ACL support that Cygwin would have.

Comment: Try to run `chgrp -R Users ~/.ssh` and then check if `chmod 0600` now works.

Comment: chgrp: invalid group: ‘Users’

Comment: Try a valid group name.

Comment: What would be a valid group name? Are we talking about default linux groups on Windows? I am confused, how are groups connected to the issue I have with chmod not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49687394/4457885) addresses the actual issue that I am having. I wrongly assumed that the permissions are the problem, that was not the case. Actually I tried modifying the permissions and even when cygwin was showing me "bad permissions" (others than the owner having read access), I could use git clone with ssh without any problems. Under Linux the ssh client stopped me from using keys with bad permissions before.

Usually I am using multiple ssh keys with different filenames (never the default filename), therefore I configure ssh to use a specific identity file with a specific host. That's why I have the config file in the first place. So don't be worried if you don't have the config file. This was my config (`C:\Users\myUser\.ssh\config`):

```
# work
Host Work-Github
  HostName work-github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_work
  PreferredAuthentications publickey

# personal
Host GitHub
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_personal
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
```

I replaced it all with the following which solved my problem:

```
AddKeysToAgent yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_work
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_personal
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am aware that Windows and it's filesystem does not support permissions

It does, even more so than Linux. Both Windows and the NTFS filesystem have the same basic "read, write, execute" permissions but also a few more such as "append" or "take ownership". Windows file permissions are also exclusively ACL-based – there are no fixed "group" or "owner" slots.

(One relevant difference is that Windows & NTFS have a *permission inheritance* system. When a file is created, its permissions get copied from the parent directory, but they're marked as "inherited" and not changeable – you have to disable inheritance in order to break the link, only then you become able to fully change them.)

When Unix-like tools such as `chmod` are ported to Windows, they need to be taught how to convert the Unix-like permissions to Windows permissions and back. Sometimes they handle it just fine, such as if you use Cygwin. But in some cases, as with the MSYS tools that come with Git for Windows, they... just don't bother with this. The MSYS 'chmod' tool was only programmed to change the file's "read-only" bit and doesn't know how to use ACLs, and likewise the MSYS 'ls' command doesn't even read them.

So if you want to make sure your SSH private key is protected, use Windows file permission tools such as `icacls` (or the GUI "Properties" dialog, of course) – first disable inheritance using `/inheritance:d`, then remove any unwanted ACEs using `/remove`. (Keep the SYSTEM entry.)

You can safely ignore what the MSYS `ls -l` command shows about the file; its output doesn't correspond to reality and it'll always pretend the file is 0644. Similarly, the MSYS `ssh` command will not complain about incorrect permissions. (The permission check is entirely client-side – the SSH server doesn't even know whether the key is stored in a file at all, much less what the file looks like.)

Comment: I have edited my post to clarify what I meant by "not supporting permissions". Sorry for the false statement.

Comment: The answer still applies – Unix-like permissions can be implemented on top of what Windows provides, but the MSYS tools shipped with Git don't bother doing that, and your assumption about the permissions being necessary for the server is a bit mistaken.

Comment: ok, how do you explain this statement on the man page of sshd ?https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config#:~:text=HostKey

Comment: That's talking about keys that the server itself uses to authenticate _to you_, not the other way around.

Comment: Guess I should read more about ssh and how it works. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you are right about the man page, but I was able to verify by just trying it out that if a private key is readable by group and global, you can not use it to clone a repo. You will get the error "Please make sure you have the correct access rights". As sson as you change back the permission to only readable by owner, you can clone your repo. (Tested under Linux) Probably the ssh client stops you from using keys with bad permissions, this check does not seem to happen under windows.

Comment: That's because the _client_ itself refuses private key files which have insecure permissions, i.e. it just skips the key without actually involving the server at all.

Answer (score 0):

Message is targeting to OP's comment about changing group to 'Users'.
I believe the name of the group is locale-dependent.
So one possible solution would be to address 'Users' group with its GID 545.
Like that:

```
chgrp 545 ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

where 'chgrp' is the utility to change group id of provided file (~/.ssh/id_ed25519 in this example) to provided group id (545 in the example, which is synonym for 'Users').